# Rendering Problems in Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

Every time I add widgets or stuff, below exception always occurs, so I can't even run my project. What causes this problem? What is the solution? I'm very new to Android Studio, and I hope you guys will help me. Every answer of you will be my pleasure. Thanks!

Here is my Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.leeroyld.testproject.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:text="@string/LoginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/LoginLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EmailDisplay"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/PasswordInput"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="?attr/actionModeBackground" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/PasswordLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PasswordDisplay"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/button_onoff_indicator_on"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/EmailInput"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="?attr/actionModeBackground"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EmailDisplay"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/PasswordInput" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your layout please.

Comment: I just updated it. Hope you see it

Comment: NO. The layout file. Switch to the Text tab and paste the code from there.

Comment: I posted it already

Comment: See the answer of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `android:backgroundTint` from `LoginButton` and `TextView`. Your final layout should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EmailDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PasswordInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:background="?attr/actionModeBackground"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PasswordDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/button_onoff_indicator_on"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmailInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EmailDisplay"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="?attr/actionModeBackground"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
</RelativeLayout>
```